# Segmentation Fault on Unicorn With Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, segmentation-fault, unicorn

I'm running into a segmentation fault on unicorn with rails 3.1 when i try to start the app, using unicorn_rails or rails console [here's](http://pastie.org/2864024) the backtrace. Can anyone help? Thanks!